# What are some things to do with teenagers in Quepos, Costa Rica?

Tags: hiking, whitewater-rafting, waterfalls

I'm heading to Quepos, Costa Rica with 4 teenagers.

We'd like to do some things like whitewater rafting, hiking, viewing waterfalls, and seeing nature and wildlife.

Comment: Welcome Smax! It looks like there are definitely some fun things to do there. Would you please answer a few questions? What time of the year are you planning to go? How long will you stay? Do you and your kids have experience with these activities, or are you looking for things at beginner levels? I'm just trying to narrow things down so we can give you better suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to the travel.stackexchange.com site

Comment: I would leave it open, because it is clearly related to outdoor activities - I think we have some older questions that are similar to this as well.

Comment: Still it is really broad...

Comment: I agree with @PaulPaulsen. We have many questions very much like this one. If we closed or migrated our "travel-recommendation" type questions, we'd lose much of our popular content.  Many are broad and opinion-based, but that's part of our culture here. Admittedly there's some confusion if you look at this type of question over the years, some get closed, some don't. This one may have an issue because OP hasn't been back yet to give more detail, but I don't think it invalidates the type of question. As always, that's just my opinion! Thank you for listening.

Comment: @Sue I opened [a meta question](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/951/7995) asking if/how I should adjust my thinking regarding close votes. While I used this question as a foil I'm really more interested in learning how I should adjust my thinking than advocating just to reclose this question.

Comment: @Wills I agree, which is why I voted to close. Since Sue's comment suggests that broad questions like this are supported I brought it up on meta to see if I should adjust my thinking.

Comment: @Erik, looking back I see I was wrong in this instance and definitely don't think you should adjust your thinking. I'm planning to respond to your meta post. I think I was definitely right to ask for more details; unsure about defending "travel-recommendation" questions; definitely wrong to defend a question this broad.

Comment: @Erik, I should have welcomed the new user, told them nicely that our system is different than others, used the help center to explain why the question needed [more details](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), explained what it means in case the question got [closed](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), and asked them to leave a comment if there was any way we could help them understand our system.

Comment: @Sue I agree that would have been better